Recreating CSS "not" using Tailwind
I'm having some difficult recreating using Tailwind some CSS I found online.
The full implementation is demoed in this code snippet: https://codepen.io/kkellydesign/pen/WNKBdqL
HTML:
<div>
  <div>
    <div></div>  
  </div>
</div>

CSS:
div{max-width: 300px;max-height: 200px; background: red; padding: 40px;}
div div {background: purple}
div div div { background: pink}

div:not(:has(div:hover)):hover {
outline: 5px solid black;
}

The specific part I'm having trouble recreating using Tailwind is
div:not(:has(div:hover)):hover

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Arbitrary variant
You could transpose the selector to an arbitrary variant. Pick a "sensible" point of reference for & to transpose. You could pick the first <div>:


div{max-width: 300px;max-height: 200px; background: red; padding: 40px;}
div div {background: purple}
div div div { background: pink}
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.16"></script>

<div class="[&:not(:has(div:hover)):hover]:outline [&:not(:has(div:hover)):hover]:outline-[5px] [&:not(:has(div:hover)):hover]:outline-black">
  <div class="[&:not(:has(div:hover)):hover]:outline [&:not(:has(div:hover)):hover]:outline-[5px] [&:not(:has(div:hover)):hover]:outline-black">
    <div class="[&:not(:has(div:hover)):hover]:outline [&:not(:has(div:hover)):hover]:outline-[5px] [&:not(:has(div:hover)):hover]:outline-black"></div>  
  </div>
</div>



Or have a container if you don't want to repeat the set of classes on every <div>:


div{max-width: 300px;max-height: 200px; background: red; padding: 40px;}
div div {background: purple}
div div div { background: pink}
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.16"></script>

<section class="[&_div:not(:has(div:hover)):hover]:outline [&_div:not(:has(div:hover)):hover]:outline-[5px] [&_div:not(:has(div:hover)):hover]:outline-black">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



Built-ins
To feel more like "Tailwind", you could also try using the built-in variants where they exist. We can break it down into two parts, the :hover, and the :not(…). We can't break :not(…) down since that will need to be an arbitrary variant since :not() does not exist as a built-in variant:


div{max-width: 300px;max-height: 200px; background: red; padding: 40px;}
div div {background: purple}
div div div { background: pink}
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.16"></script>

<div class="hover:[&:not(:has(div:hover))]:outline hover:[&:not(:has(div:hover))]:outline-[5px] hover:[&:not(:has(div:hover))]:outline-black">
  <div class="hover:[&:not(:has(div:hover))]:outline hover:[&:not(:has(div:hover))]:outline-[5px] hover:[&:not(:has(div:hover))]:outline-black">
    <div class="hover:[&:not(:has(div:hover))]:outline hover:[&:not(:has(div:hover))]:outline-[5px] hover:[&:not(:has(div:hover))]:outline-black"></div>
  </div>
</div>



Plugin
You can also abstract any of the arbitrary variants used previously to a custom variant using a Tailwind plugin:


tailwind.config = {
  plugins: [
    tailwind.plugin(({ addVariant }) => {
      addVariant('foo', '&:not(:has(div:hover)):hover');
      addVariant('bar', '& div:not(:has(div:hover)):hover');
      addVariant('baz', '&:not(:has(div:hover))');
    }),
  ],
};
div{max-width: 300px;max-height: 200px; background: red; padding: 40px;}
div div {background: purple}
div div div { background: pink}
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.16"></script>

<div class="foo:outline foo:outline-[5px] foo:outline-black">
  <div class="foo:outline foo:outline-[5px] foo:outline-black">
    <div class="foo:outline foo:outline-[5px] foo:outline-black"></div>  
  </div>
</div>

<section class="bar:outline bar:outline-[5px] bar:outline-black">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="hover:baz:outline hover:baz:outline-[5px] hover:baz:outline-black">
  <div class="hover:baz:outline hover:baz:outline-[5px] hover:baz:outline-black">
    <div class="hover:baz:outline hover:baz:outline-[5px] hover:baz:outline-black"></div>
  </div>
</div>




works perfect! I was trying for the longest time to use arbitrary variants but couldn't get it to come to come together. Works great now! Thanks
